# Multiple divs to slidetoggle, how to hide all on with a close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have 3 divs that toggle when their relative link is clicked. When a div is toggled and another is already active, it replaces the "previous":

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".toggleddivs").hide();
  jQuery('.togglelink').click(function(){
    jQuery(".toggleddivs").hide();
    jQuery("#"+jQuery(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>

<a class="togglelink" data-target="div1">togglelink1</a>
<a class="togglelink" data-target="div2">togglelink2</a>
<a class="togglelink" data-target="div3">togglelink3</a>

<div class="toggleddivs" id="div1">CONTENT_DIV1 <a class="toggle" data-target="div1">CLOSE</a></div>
<div class="toggleddivs" id="div2">CONTENT_DIV2 <a class="toggle" data-target="div2">CLOSE</a></div>
<div class="toggleddivs" id="div3">CONTENT_DIV3 <a class="toggle" data-target="div3">CLOSE</a></div>
```

DEMO (it's like this in my live site): http://jsfiddle.net/RKVY7/

It works fine, except that

1) I don't know how to make the close button to work (see demo)

2) when the div is toggled the page moves up. How can I "block" the position of the page?

Answer (score 0):

1) You will need to change the class name w/in your divs from "toggle" to something else like "close" for instance, and then add this: (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RKVY7/2/))

```
  jQuery('.close').click(function(){
    jQuery(".comefareper").slideUp( "slow", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
  });
```

2) You will need to save the current scroll before your code run and once it's done set it back to the saved position:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".comefareper").hide();

  var currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  jQuery('.toggle').click(function(){
    jQuery(".comefareper").hide();
    jQuery("#"+jQuery(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
    $(window).scrollTop(currentScrollTop);
  });

   jQuery('.close').click(function(){
    jQuery(".comefareper").slideUp( "slow", function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(window).scrollTop(currentScrollTop);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So after all i manipulated plenty of your JS-code to beware you from the [callback-hell](http://callbackhell.com/).
After all you should use classes for the elements. It was hard to look through your code. But heres the result:

***[jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/RKVY7/7/)](http://jsfiddle.net/RKVY7/7/)***

***HTML***

```
<a class="togglelink" data-target="div1">togglelink1</a>
<a class="togglelink" data-target="div2">togglelink2</a>
<a class="togglelink" data-target="div3">togglelink3</a>
<div class="container">
    <div class="toggleddivs" id="div1">CONTENT_DIV1 <a class="toggle" data-target="div1">CLOSE</a></div>
    <div class="toggleddivs" id="div2">CONTENT_DIV2 <a class="toggle" data-target="div2">CLOSE</a></div>
    <div class="toggleddivs" id="div3">CONTENT_DIV3 <a class="toggle" data-target="div3">CLOSE</a></div>
</div>
```

***CSS*** (for .container)

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin : 0;
}
```

***JS***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // INT
    // the height of the highest one
    var highestcomefareper = 0;

    // get highest comefareper so it will not scroll up.
    var _gethighestcomefareper = function () {
        var _height = jQuery(this).height();
        if(highestcomefareper<_height) {
            highestcomefareper = _height;
        }
    };

    // It's not a "real toggle". Just close all and slide down the one
    var _togglecomefareper = function(){
        var _target = jQuery(this).data('target');
        jQuery(".comefareper").hide();
        jQuery("#"+_target).slideDown();
    };

    // close the nearest element with the class "comefareper". So don't use it in these boxes again
    var _closecomefareper = function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.comefareper').slideUp(); 
    };

    // Get highest comefareper
    jQuery(".comefareper").each(_gethighestcomefareper);

    // Assign height to the container. (Prevents page from up-scrolling on close)
    jQuery(".container").css("min-height", highestcomefareper + "px");

    // Hide All
    jQuery(".comefareper").hide();

    // Assign functions to the buttons
    jQuery('.toggle').click(_togglecomefareper);
    jQuery(".close").click(_closecomefareper);
});
```